# Magento: _setResourceModel override to change collection name

Tags: magento

Please can someone please show me **real world** example of when it would be advisable to override _setResourceModel to provide different name for collection.

I find it fascinating that magento have given the option of using a custom word for "_collection" but that there is absolutely no evidence of it ever being done.

Comment: Would you rather have a system that allows you to do this is you think of a reason to do it, or a system that doesn't allow you to do it if you realize you HAVE to do it?

Answer (score -2):

You might want to have a different name for _collection if you are using multiple datastores

(for example: if you are using MySql and MongoDB).

Pesach

Comment: I'm not sure that is 100% correct.  From the little I know, I understood the data access layer to be abstracted away so the collection and resource model did not have to know anything about the actual data store